# React: why do you have to bind this method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binding

I'm reading [this article](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) on "Lifting State Up" in React. It defines the `Calculator` component as follows:

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {temperature: ''};
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.state.temperature;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature in Celsius:</legend>
        <input
          value={temperature}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />

        <BoilingVerdict
          celsius={parseFloat(temperature)} />

      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
```

In the line `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`, I'm wondering why we have to bind `this.handleChange` to `this`. It's used in the line `onChange={this.handleChange}`. Wouldn't this work the same even if we hadn't done that binding?

Comment: The `this` inside `handleChange` would refer to the method and not to the component instance (`Calculator`). Since `handleChange` does not have a `setState` method (the component does) we have to bind the correct `this` in the method. If you had another method that was not doing anything with `this`, then yes, you could skip the bind.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Want to put this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` inside `handleChange` would refer to the method and not to the component instance (`Calculator`). Since `handleChange` does not have a `setState` method (the component does) we have to bind the correct `this` in the method. If you had another method that was not doing anything with `this`, then yes, you could skip the bind.

From the official docs:

> If you need to have access to the parent component in the handler, you also need to bind the function to the component instance.

A way to circumvent this is to either use the [fat arrow syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#class-properties-stage-3-proposal) (as in Dimitar's answer) or use the [React Hook API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

---

In other words (see comments):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {temperature: ''};
}

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});
  // ^ this = handleChange. You cannot call setState on handleChange.
}
```

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.state = {temperature: ''};
}

handleChange(e) {
  this.setState({temperature: e.target.value});
  // ^ this = Calculator component. All React (class) Components have setState
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with scopes, and is something that ES6 solves by implementing fat arrow functions.

Basically when you create a method inside of a class in JavaScript, that method does not instantly inherit `this`, so any reference to `this` will result in an error. To solve this, you need to bind the function to `this` which basically virtually passes down an instance of the class to the function as a parameter (if you look in the background).

If you want to avoid this binding, you can just use a fat arrow function like so:

```
handleChange = e => this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
```

In that basic example, I referenced `this` without having bound the method to `this` and didnt get an error because fat arrow functions are automatically bound to `this`

Comment: This is great, thanks! I told Chris above that I'd approve his answer because he got there first, but your comments about arrow functions add some extra insight that I needed.

Comment: I don't personally care about reputation, but in general you would approve the most accurate or the best answer for the next person who might need help.

Comment: Your answers are both accurate. I wouldn't say one's more accurate than the other. That's why I chose to approve his but upvote both.